# trying to build JS gantt and background color disappear when scrolled

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to web programming, and took a course in HTML, CSS and JS.
In the course I was given an exercise to build a Gantt.
Meanwhile I created only the scale of the Gantt.

But when I scroll - the background disappeared!

I uploaded the code to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4aptG/9/).

```
<body dir="rtl">
<div id='gantt_here' style='width:100%; height:100%;'>
    <div id='gantt_tasks'  class='gantt_tasks' style='width:99%; height:99%;'>
        <div id='gantt_task_scale' class='gantt_task_scale'></div>
        <div id='gantt_task_data_area' class='gantt_task_data_area'></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS (part):

```
.gantt_task_scale{
/*  position:absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px; */

/*  overflow:visible; */

/*  padding:16px 20px 17px 15px;  */

    border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
    border-bottom:1px solid #e0e0e0;  


    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fbfbfb', endColorstr='#fafafa'); /* for IE */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fbfbfb), to(#fafafa)); /*  for webkit browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #fbfbfb,  #fafafa); /* for firefox 3.6+  */ 
}
```

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.taskScale{
display:inline-block; 
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fbfbfb', endColorstr='#fafafa'); /* for IE */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fbfbfb), to(#fafafa)); /*  for webkit browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #fbfbfb,  #fafafa); /* for firefox 3.6+  */
```

}

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4aptG/10/)

Comment: thank you, it fix the issue in chrome and IE, but for some reason, the broswer in eclipse doesn't present the color even after the change.